# What does "Origin Summary" mean in this PageSpeed Insight report?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I recently noticed that Google updated the PageSpeed Insight report page. There is an "Origin Summary".

[image]

What does it exactly mean? Why it's slightly different than the field data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the page you are testing has enough visitors you will see your "field data". That is real world performance **for that page**

The origin summary is real world performance data **for all pages on the domain** where there is enough data.

Basically it is page performance (Field Data) vs site performance as a whole (Origin Summary).

Comment: This nomenclature is unnecessarily arcane. Would URL and Domain not have been much better choices?